# Spread polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Norman Wildberger's "rational trigonometry" has been viewed by some mathematicians as a clever new take on an ancient topic.  Wildberger's ["spread polynomials"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_polynomials) $S_n$ are characterized by the identity
$$
\sin^2(n\theta) = S_n(\sin^2\theta)
$$
(except that Wildberger refuses to refer explicitly to the sine function in the definition and does it by other means).  In one sense these are trivially equivalent to the Chebyshev polynomials $T_n$ characterized by
$$
\cos(n\theta) = T_n(\cos\theta).
$$
Wildberger notes that $1 - 2S_n(s) = T_n(1 - 2s)$.

In thinking about whether this polynomial sequence is even worth mentioning after Chebyshev polynomials have been treated, three questions come to mind:

- Could it be that an essential difference justifying a separate treatment is the factorization of these polynomials?  Wildberger factors the spread polynomials.  Is there some important reason for doing that?
- Is there a combinatorial interpretation of the coefficients?  The coefficient of the $n$th-degree term in $S_n$ for $n=1,\dots,10$ is $n^2$ and the coefficient of the constant term is $4^{n-1}$.  The first-degree term is $n/2$ times the constant term.
- If there's no essential difference that justifies attending to the two sequences separately, the fact that the conventional way of viewing the sequence (Chebyshev polynomials) is chronologically first, doesn't mean it's necessarily better than Wildberger's way of viewing it (spread polynomials).  Is it?

Comment: what do you mean by "factorization"? Over integers? Then it is well known for Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: OK, my statement about "not much written" on factoring Chebyshev polynomials may have been rash.  I did mean over integers, but maybe over complex numbers to if that's of interest.  So the first question above is whether differences in the way they factor might justify separate attention to the two sequences.

Comment: Per your (seeming?) suggestion I've deleted that comment from the question.

Comment: Who are "some mathematicians" who view this as a clever new take on an ancient topic?  It seems to me that geometric algebra (in the sense of Artin) subsumes all that stuff and it's been known for quite some time before Wildberger's book appeared. 

Comment: The books are different in purpose. Artin just gives you the axioms to do geometry over arbitrary fields. Now if you actually want to take all those myriads of geometrical theorems that have been proven over $\mathbb R$ and make the proofs work over any field, you need to construct analogues of the standard methods of elementary geometry - vectors, transformations, lengths, angles, trigonometric functions, etc. - that would work over any field. Now, with vectors and transformations this is trivial, but lengths (being square roots), angles (being transcendental), trig functions (due to the ...

Comment: ... unclarity about what an angle is) are much harder. It is clear that these concepts OUGHT TO BE rational, since geometry itself ought to be rational and work over every field of characteristic $\neq 2$ (and $\neq 3$ for things such as centroids of triangles), but when we are doing geometry the classical way we keep using this irrational and transcendental stuff. Wildberger tried to avoid it. I wouldn't say he completely succeeded, but his texts have some substance as far as I saw (was quite a while ago, however).

Comment: Oh, and of course, when working over arbitrary fields, you might want to assume $\sqrt 2$ to lie in the field for having squares, and $\sqrt 3$ for having equilateral triangles. The good news is that if you have, for instance, a proof for Napoleon's theorem over any field with $\sqrt 3$ in it, then it automatically also proves Napoleon's theorem with the equilateral triangles pointing inside instead of outside - because the field $\mathbb Q\left(X\right)\left(\sqrt 3\right)$ "won't notice" if you replace $\sqrt 3$ by $-\sqrt 3$ (this is a case of what John Horton Conway calls "extraversion").

Comment: So the whole thing is not useless. But as far as I recall from a short glance at his books, Wildberger succeeds rationalizing only a small part of geometry. He mainly replaces lengths by length squares, and angles by sine squares, and goes on to prove some formulas and properties of these. He does not suceed at relating length squares to ratios of lengths on the same line (which are also rational, because they are actually ratios of vectors), sine squares to ratios of sines of angles at the same point (like one needs, e. g., for the trig version of Ceva's theorem) and cotangents (which are...

Comment: ... rational, as well). So it's not a revolution as the cover text claims.

Comment: In answer to the 3rd question, the Spread Polynomials are positive on the unit interval, mapping it onto itself.

Comment: @TomSpeight : I don't actually know whether you're saying that the traditional way of viewing these things (Chebyshev polynomials) is better or worse that Wildberger's way (spread polynomials).

Comment: @StefanKohl You've actually commented on the question itself, not someone's answer.

Answer (score 13):

Regarding which point of view is preferable, I don't see that there's much difference between them.  The Chebyshev polynomials map $[-1,1]$ to $[-1,1]$, the spread polynomials map $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and they are conjugate under a linear map between $[-1,1]$ and $[0,1]$, so all their properties translate easily between the two frameworks.

However, I'd vote for Chebyshev polynomials as being somewhat more fundamental, due to orthogonality.  The spread polynomials aren't orthogonal with respect to any measure, because they are nonnegative everywhere.  To get orthogonality, one must subtract $1/2$, after which they become orthogonal with respect to $dx/\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ on the interval $[0,1]$.  By contrast, the Chebyshev polynomials are already orthogonal with respect to $dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$, with no subtraction needed.  This isn't a big deal, since it just amounts to subtracting $1/2$, but it's nice not to have to do the subtraction.

Overall, there's nothing sacred about using the domain $[-1,1]$ for Chebyshev polynomials.  Of course it aligns beautifully with trigonometry, but Chebyshev polynomials are important in many other settings (such as approximation theory) in which $[-1,1]$ plays no special role, and they are simply rescaled to fit the interval of interest.  From that perspective, $[0,1]$ is just as good a domain.  On the other hand, I see no gain from making the range $[0,1]$ as well, and one has to undo it to recover orthogonality.

Comments added in edit:

As for the factorizations, this amounts to factoring $T_n(x)$ (for Chebyshev polynomials) or $T_n(x)+1$ (for spread polynomials - **not quite, see comments below**).  Both are interesting, since both the roots and the extrema of the Chebyshev polynomials are important.

In fact, $T_{2n}(x)= T_2(T_n(x))$ and hence $T_{2n}(x)+1 = 2T_n(x)^2$, so factoring spread polynomials includes factoring Chebyshev polynomials as the even-index case.  (In the odd-index case, $T_{2n+1}(x)+1 = (T_{n+1}(x)+T_n(x))^2/(x+1)$, but I'm not certain how to interpret this.)

So I'd say factoring spread polynomials is more general but slightly more obscure.  Definitely both are interesting, though.

There are combinatorial interpretations of the Chebyshev polynomials involving weighted monomer-dimer configurations (although the conditions are a little odd: see http://www.math.hmc.edu/~benjamin/papers/CombTrig.pdf).  The analogous idea doesn't work out as nicely for spread polynomials, but maybe some other approach is more appropriate.  It's worth noting that the Chebyshev polynomials have somewhat simpler coefficients.  For example, $T_8(x)=128x^8-256x^6+160x^4-32x^2+1$ while $S_8(x)=-16384x^8 + 65536x^7 - 106496x^6 + 90112x^5 - 42240x^4 + 10752x^3 - 1344x^2 + 64x$.

Comment: OK, you've answered part of what I asked very well.  I'm still wondering whether the factorizations hold some interest not available in the Chebyshev polynomials.  And usually there's also a combinatorial interpreation.

Comment: @ Henry: I don't know spread polynomials. But if it is true as stated above that $$ 1-2S_n(x)=T_n(1-2x)$$ then $$1+T_n(x)$$ does not coincide with spread polynomials except that $$ 2S_{2n+1}(x^2)=T_{4n+2}(x)+1=2T_{2n+1}(x)^2.$$ 

Comment: Oops, yeah: I chose the wrong extrema.  In the odd case, $1-T_n(x) = 1+T_n(-x)$, so it doesn't really matter up to signs, but the even case seems to be genuinely different.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, still digesting stuff.....

Maybe it's generally harder to notice patterns in the coefficients of the Chebyshev polynomials because the patterns are simpler.

Answer (score 6):

Factorization of the spread polynomials can be reduced to the factorization of the Chebyshev polynomials by observing that
$$ 1-T_{2n+2}(x)=2 U_n(x)^2 (1-x^2)$$
and
$$ 1-T_{2n+3}(x)=(U_{n+1}(x)+U_n(x))^2 (1-x).$$
Edit:
The following formulae show the connection between the factorization of spread  polynomials and Chebyshev polynomials most clearly:
$$ S_{2n}(x^2)= (1-x^2)U_{2n-1}(x)^2 $$
and
$$ S_{2n+1}(x^2)= T_{2n+1}(x)^2.$$

Comment: That's nice!  I hadn't noticed that $S_n(x^2)$ had such a beautiful expression in terms of Chebyshev polynomials.  This really makes me want a slick way to deal with both types of Chebyshev polynomials at once.  I guess the point must be that the functions $\sqrt{1-x^2} U_n(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to the same measure as $T_n(x)$, namely $dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$.

Any idea what happens to the even-degree polynomials?  If $(1-x^2)U_{2n-1}(x)^2$ and $T_{2n+1}(x)^2$ are spread polynomials (up to substituting $x^2$ for $x$), then what are $(1-x^2)U_{2n}(x)^2$ and $T_{2n}(x)^2$?

Comment: Let  $$ 2V_n(x)=1+T_n(1-2x).$$ Then 
$$ V_{2n}(x^2)= T_{2n}(x)^2$$ 
and
$$ V_{2n+1}(x^2)= (1-x^2)U_{2n}(x)^2. $$


Comment: A further remark. These polynomials are characterized by
`$$\cos^2(n\theta) = V_n(\sin^2\theta)$$`


Comment: I calculated $$S_{2n}(x^2)=1-T_{2n}^2(x)$$. So we dont need to consider the Chebychev polynomial of the 2nd kind. Hope that is correct.